# WPF Text Formatting Issue with Dynamically Created TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

While there are a few questions on the site about formatting text in WPF textboxes, this issue only occurs on a small set of computers. If there is a similar question already, please point me to it!

I have a WPF application that is used to get resource usage and perform diagnostic/recovery tasks on remote servers. When a command is run, a textbox is created in c# to display the resulting output. On most computers the text prints out fine. However, on a small handful of computers and a VDI my team uses the output seems to hit a boundary and truncate the last column of my output (see screenshots).

[Normal output on success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5Xhk.jpg)

[Output seems to hit a boundary that doesn't occur on most computers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fueBr.jpg)

c# for creating tabitem and children including the textbox:

```
        TabItem currentButtonTab = buttonTabControl.SelectedItem as TabItem;
        TabItem resultsTab = new TabItem();
        TextBox resultsTabText = new TextBox();
        Grid resultsGrid = new Grid();
        Grid tabLabelGrid = new Grid();
        Button closeTabCmd = new Button();
        DockPanel tabPanel = new DockPanel();
        StackPanel tabLabelPanel = new StackPanel();
        Label tabLabel = new Label();

        resultsTabText.Style = (Style)Resources["txtStyle"];
        //resultsTabText.Margin = new Thickness(5);
        //resultsTabText.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
        resultsTabText.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
        resultsTabText.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, 2);
        resultsTabText.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        resultsTabText.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
        resultsTabText.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
        //resultsTabText.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Consolas");
        resultsTabText.IsReadOnly = true;
        resultsTabText.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        resultsTabText.MaxLines = 20;
        resultsTabText.Tag = string.Format("resultsText");

        tabPanel.Margin = new Thickness(0);
        tabPanel.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
        tabPanel.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, 2);
        tabPanel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        tabPanel.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

        resultsTab.Padding = new Thickness(5, 0, 5, 0);
        resultsTab.Content = resultsGrid;
        resultsTab.Header = tabLabelGrid;
        resultsTab.Name = string.Format("resultTab{0}", currentTabCount + 1);
        resultsTab.Style = (Style)Resources["TabItemTemplate"];
        resultsTab.Focus();

        closeTabCmd.Click += clearButton_Click;
        closeTabCmd.Tag = resultsTab.Name;
        closeTabCmd.Margin = new Thickness(0);
        closeTabCmd.Padding = new Thickness(1, -3, 1, -2);
        closeTabCmd.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        closeTabCmd.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        closeTabCmd.Content = "X";
        closeTabCmd.Background = Brushes.WhiteSmoke;
        closeTabCmd.Foreground = Brushes.Red;

        tabLabelGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0,-5,0,-5);
        tabLabelGrid.Children.Add(tabLabelPanel);

        tabLabel.Content = computerName + "-" + buttonName;
        tabLabel.Style = (Style)Resources["dynamicLabelStyle"];

        tabLabelPanel.Margin = new Thickness(0);
        tabLabelPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        tabLabelPanel.Children.Add(tabLabel);
        tabLabelPanel.Children.Add(closeTabCmd);

        resultsTabControl.SelectionChanged += ResultsTabControl_SelectionChanged;

        resultsTabControl.Items.Add(resultsTab);
        resultsGrid.Children.Add(tabPanel);
        tabPanel.Children.Add(resultsTabText);
```

XAML showing the style applied and the parent tabcontrol:

```
    <Style x:Key="txtStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Consolas"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    </Style>
    ...
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    ...
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="copyButton" Style="{StaticResource closeTabButton}" 
                Click="copyCmd_Click" Content="Copy Current Text"/>
            <Button x:Name="closeTabsCmd" Style="{StaticResource closeTabButton}" 
                Click="closeTabsCmd_Click" Content="Close All"/>
            <Button x:Name="copyCmd" Margin="5" Padding="2" Click="copyCmd_Click" Content="Copy" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TabControl x:Name="resultsTabControl" Visibility="Collapsed" Style="{StaticResource resultsControl}" 
            ButtonBase.Click="clearButton_Click" SelectionChanged="ResultsTabControl_SelectionChanged">
            <TabControl.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFF9F9F9" Opacity="0.1"/>
            </TabControl.Background>
        </TabControl>
    </StackPanel>
```

I've confirmed this happens regardless of .NET version installed. This is absolutely driving me insane. In hopes of keeping this as brief as possible I omitted code above I thought was irrelevant but will gladly post more if needed. any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you check that the output from the remote computer isn't where the wrapping is occurring? I was thinking about something like this if you're using powershell, just to rule out the possibility https://greiginsydney.com/viewing-truncated-powershell-output/

Comment: Maybe it's a  video card driver issue ?

Comment: So when you say "prints out", you mean "displays on the screen"?

Comment: That worked @rmc00! Can you write that as an answer so I can mark it? I'm so glad this was a Powershell fix as the script is run from a network location and not compiled with the application so took 2 seconds to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes PowerShell truncates its output very similar to what you're seeing. One way you can fix it is to pipe the command's output through out-string to set the width like this:

```
your-command | out-string -Width 160
```

Depending on your scenario, there are other ways to control formatting of powershell output. See https://greiginsydney.com/viewing-truncated-powershell-output/